# How to display images from web service?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-json, android-webservice, android-json-rpc

I wanted to fetch the images from the URL but the whole code is clean but there is no output i am getting. what should i do.

I used the whole code from this URL

http://www.sanktips.com/2017/10/15/how-to-fetch-images-from-server-to-image-slider-with-viewpager-in-android-studio/#comment-43

And this is the error what i am getting.

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

```
This is the mainactivity

    package com.example.admin.serverslider;

import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
    private int dotscount;
    private ImageView[] dots;

    RequestQueue rq;
    List<SliderUtils> sliderImg;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    /* String request_url = "http://localhost/sliderjsonoutput.php";*/
    String request_url = "http://georeachtech.com/missing.org/fetch_home_page_data.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rq = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        sliderImg = new ArrayList<>();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

        sendRequest();


        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++) {
                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactivate));
                }

                dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.activate));

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });


    }


    public void sendRequest() {

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, request_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    SliderUtils sliderUtils = new SliderUtils();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        //  sliderUtils.setSliderImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                        sliderUtils.setSliderImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    sliderImg.add(sliderUtils);
                }
                viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(sliderImg, MainActivity.this);

                viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

                dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
                dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

                for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++) {

                    dots[i] = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactivate));

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

                    sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

                }

                dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.activate));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("error", error.toString());

            }
        });
        rq.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}






    **This the custom volly class:**








import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;



public class CustomVolleyRequest {
    private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context){

        this.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });

    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context){

        if(customVolleyRequest == null){
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){

        if(requestQueue == null){

            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            requestQueue.start();

        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public  void addToRequestQueue(Request req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader(){

        return imageLoader;

    }


}
```

**This the Adapter class**

```
package com.example.admin.serverslider;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by admin on 12/19/2017.
 */

public class ViewPagerAdapter  extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<SliderUtils> sliderImg;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;


    public ViewPagerAdapter(List sliderImg,Context context) {
        this.sliderImg = sliderImg;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sliderImg.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);

        SliderUtils utils = sliderImg.get(position);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(utils.getSliderImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(position == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Slide 1 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(position == 1){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Slide 2 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Slide 3 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);

    }
}
```

Comment: this question lacks very basic information. What code are you using to actually to fetch the images.

Comment: have you seen the URL?Which i mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please go through the site rules at the [help]. All pertinent information, including your [mcve] code should be **in your question** not in a link.

Comment: OK i understood

Answer (score 0):

The link looks valid and working so the possibilities are either

- You don't have correct Internet permissions

In which case add following to the menifest file;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

or

- You do have internet permission the phone doesn't have connectivity. Are you able to browse anything else on the internet on the devise? If its the emulator try restarting or recreating the device.

Comment: I already added that user permission in the manifest file.It should have worked.But i don't know whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
request = new JsonArrayRequest(request_url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;

                for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {



                    SliderUtils sliderUtils = new SliderUtils();

                    try {
                          jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                          sliderUtils.setSliderImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("image1"));


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    sliderImg.add(sliderUtils);

                }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)